# 'tee' device: Can i pipe to a FIFO and sample the data when i wish

Tags: linux

I am piping a sequence through a PIPE to another program (mkfifo) on Linux. Is there a way for me to sample the data being read, periodically and see what's going on?

> seq 99999999 -1 00000000 >/tmp/foo 
>   pyrit -r cap/ZUTUMS-01.cap -i /tmp/foo attack_passthrough

How do i see where i am in the sequence whenever I feel like it. I don't want to write to disk or stdout. I could use strace but that's overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use [Pipe Viewer](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/pv-command-examples/)

It can give you such info as:

- Time elapsed
- Percentage completed (with progress bar)
- Current throughput rate
- Total data transferred
- ETA